# Webpack dynamic url api

Tags: webpack

I have some trouble with webpack and my api url.
I have a build with Jenkins who deploy my app on two server

I have two backend url (same as frontend url) :

- Recette : 12.122.125.208
- Prod : 12.122.125.209

My webpack config :

```
build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
```

My prod.env file :

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  URL_API: '"http://12.122.125.208/api/"',
};
```

It's possible to have dynamic URL based on current URL something like :

```
const = BASE_URL;
URL_API: BASE_URL + '/api/"',
```

With that, I can deploy one time for my two server

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure multiple Jenkins "[Parameterized Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)", and have different profiles:

- deploy to "Recette": `BASE_URL=12.122.125.208`
- deploy to "Prod": `BASE_URL=12.122.125.209`

And then access this `BASE_URL` from your webpack config using `process.env.BASE_URL`.